# Como fazer com que um menu se repita até uma opção válda?

Tags: c++, loop, menu, switch

Estou fazendo um programa em C++ que deve gerar três números e organizá-los de acordo com a escolha do usuário, duas opções são fornecidas e ele deve escolher uma, mas não sei como fazer para que o menu peça uma escolha válida e dê as opções novamente caso o usuário escolha uma opção inválida, tentei usar o while e o do while, mas apenas consegui que ele lesse a variável novamente e na executasse a ordenação.
Este é o código sem as minhas tentativas com o laço de repetição:

```
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"");
    int x,y,z,escolha;
    printf("Digite três valores inteiros para X, Y e Z\n");
    scanf ("%d", &x);
    printf("X é igual a: %d\n",x);
    scanf("%d", &y);
    printf("Y é igual a: %d\n",y);
    scanf("%d", &z);
    printf("Z é igual a: %d\n",z);
    printf("Escolha uma das ordenações: \n1-Ordem não decrescente;\n2-Ordem não crescente.");
    scanf("%d", &escolha);
    switch (escolha){
        case 1:
        printf("Odernação escolhida: Não decrescente.\n");
            // Quando X e Y > Z
            if ((x>y) && (y>z) || (y>x) && (x>z)){
                printf("Em ordem não decrescente, temos: Z (%d), Y (%d) e X (%d).\n",z,y,x);
            }
            // Quando X e Z > Y
            else if ((x>z) && (z>y) || (z>x) && (x>y)){
                printf("Em ordem não decrescente, temos: Y (%d), Z (%d) e X (%d).\n",y,z,x);
            }
            // Quando Y e Z > X
            else if ((y>z) && (z>x) || (z>y) && (y>x)){
                printf("Em ordem não decrescente, temos: X (%d), Z (%d) e Y (%d).\n",x,z,y);
            }
        break;
        case 2:
        printf("Odernação escolhida: Não crescente.\n");
            // Quando X e Y < Z
            if ((x<y) && (y<z) || (y<x) && (x<z)){
            printf("Em ordem não crescente, temos: Z (%d), Y (%d) e X (%d).\n",z,y,x);
            }
            // Quando X e Z < Y
            else if ((x<z) && (z<y) || (z<x) && (x<y)){
            printf("Em ordem não crescente, temos: Y (%d), Z (%d) e X (%d).\n",y,z,x);
            }
            // Quando Y e Z < X
            else if ((y<z) && (z<x) || (z<y) && (y<x)){
            printf("Em ordem não crescente, temos: X (%d), Z (%d) e Y (%d).\n",x,z,y);
            }
        break;
        default:
        printf("Opção inválida, tente novamente\n");
    }

    return 0;
    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Normalmente para situações assim, utilizamos de um loop, enquanto a opção for inválida o menu é exibido novamente.

---

Podemos optar por fazer isso com o `do/while`, que exibirá uma vez o menu e caso a opção seja inválida, será exibido novamente:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  int escolha;
  int invalido;

  do {
    printf("Opções 1, 2 ou 3:\n");
    scanf("%d", &escolha);
    invalido= 0;

    switch(escolha) {
      case 1:
        printf("Opção 1");
        break;
      case 2:
        printf("Opção 2");
        break;
      case 3:
        printf("Opção 3");
        break;
      default:
        printf("Opção inválida\n");
        invalido= 1;
        break;
    }
  } while (invalido);

  return 0;
}
```

> Veja online: https://repl.it/@Dadinel/OrdinaryUnkemptDecimals